# How could I improve this "step based" python chat server and client so it supports more than two instances?

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

Here is the server:

```
import socket


HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4444

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print addr, 'connected.'

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print '> ', data
    reply = raw_input(">> ")
    conn.sendall(reply)
    if reply == 'bye':
        break

conn.close()
```

And here is the client:

```
import socket

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 4444


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
while True:
    message = raw_input("> ")
    s.send(message)
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    print ">> ", repr(reply)
    if message == 'bye':
        break

s.close()
```

What is the most efficient way to upgrade this code to support multiple instances, and more importantly: how could I assign names (nicknames) to all clients and make it so clients could type whenever they want? I tried to use Threading, but that was a huge **disaster** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Multiple client**

For multiple client connection, you need to have some non-linear execution.
You can either use coroutines or threads to achieve this.

Python 3 comes with [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), library that uses coroutines (and lot of other features) to *emulate* multithreading. I suggest you look into this.

You can also use threads, it's not that complicated. Whenever a client connects to your server, you just have to create a new thread to execute your function. [Python official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib2.html#multi-threading) should help you achieve that.

**Nickname**

Whenever a client connects to your server, you could instantiate a User object in the newly created thread with your client information, so that each thread has its own User instance.